# How do I set the date after 1 day in type string and ddMMyyyyHHmm for Spring?

Tags: java, spring, date, validation

`smsRequest.setEndDate(1 day later);` /// TODO 1 day later

I want to set the date after 1 day to the variable endDate, which is held as a string and of type ddMMyyyyHHmm. How can I give?

Comment: Holding your end date and time in a `String`? Don’t! Use a `LocalDateTime` or another datetime object. Are you keeping numbers and Boolean values in strings too? ;-P And use the `plusDays` method of `LocalDateTIme` to add a day.

Comment: Actually, it wasn't my choice. :( Since the outbound service expects a value like this, I'm trying to do it accordingly.

Comment: I consider your question too broad for Stack Overflow. Please search for how to add 1 day to a date and time and for how to format the result of that into a string in the format you mention. It’s described in thousands of places. During your search ignore pages and answers suggesting to use the old and poorly designed classes like `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat`. Go for those using [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: A starting point could be something like `ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Antarctica/Casey")).plusDays(1).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("ddMMuuuuHHmm"))`. It just gave `070920221411`.

Comment: You're a great person, thank yo! It worked that way. I never know if I should use a format like this. I guess I need to learn how to research it in the first place.

Comment: Always search Stack Overflow thoroughly before posting. Your issues have been addressed many many times already.